# Deleting list items with SwipeView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I've made a contacts app in Xamarin and wanted to incorporate the SwipeView, but I can't figure out how to delete single contacts from my list. Any help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using Contacts.Classes;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Contacts
{
    public partial class ContactsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ContactsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Device.SetFlags(new[] {"SwipeView_Experimental"});

        }

        void NewContactToolbarItem_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Contact>();
                var contacts = conn.Table<Contact>().ToList();

                contactsListView.ItemsSource = contacts;

                Command DeleteCommand = new Command<Contact>(contact => { conn.Delete(contact); });
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. use an ObservableCollections instead of a List, 2) maintain your contacts as a class level variable, 3) when deleting, delete from your class level contacts AND your db, 4) your db delete needs to establish a db connection, you cannot reuse the conn the way you are currently trying to

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, create a database access class include connection, deleting operation and so on. You could check the database access class in the link below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases#data-manipulation-methods

Choose the Item you want to delete and invoke the delete method of SQLite database.

```
conn.DeleteAsync(item);
```

After deleting the Item, use the code below to get the list of database and reset the ItemSource.

```
conn.Table<Contact>().ToListAsync();
```

You could download the source file from the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/